# Google OAUTH2: error_description: 'Invalid client_id parameter value

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

From google cloud, I got Client ID and Client secret

[image]

[image]

In my login.jsx, I copy and paste those client_id and client_secret but I am getting

[image]

Invalid client_id parameter value when I try to sign in with google account.

I'm following this https://medium.com/@ronakchitlangya1997/social-authentication-email-using-django-and-react-js-e1cc8456262d explanation to do this, but I really cannot figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not a screenshot.